# Custom error pages for 404, 500 but where is the default 500 error message coming from?

Tags: error-handling, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently in production I'm getting this text:

```
500 Internal Server Error
If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's
log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong.
```

There isn't any HTML on that page. Where is this code situated? I don't have a *public/500.html* file.

In my routes I have:

```
  get "/404", :to => "errors#error_404"
  get "/422", :to => "errors#error_404"
  get "/500", :to => "errors#error_500"
  get "/505", :to => "errors#error_505"
```

ErrorsController:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController

  def sub_layout
    "left"
  end

  def error_404
    render :status => 404, :formats => [:html], :layout => "white", :sub_layout => "left"
  end

  def error_422
    render :status => 422, :formats => [:html], :layout => "white", :sub_layout => "left"
  end

  def error_500
    render :status => 500, :formats => [:html], :layout => "white", :sub_layout => "left"
  end

  def error_505
    render :status => 505, :formats => [:html], :layout => "white", :sub_layout => "left"
  end

end
```

How do I make it load my custom errors always? On some errors, it just throws those two lines of text coming somewhere from the Ruby on Rails core. I want it to pickup my custom styled error pages every time!

Comment: http://blog.grepruby.com/2015/04/custom-error-pages-with-rails-4.html

Comment: This article has a concise explanation of where this Rails error page is displayed, under 'drawbacks': https://mattbrictson.com/dynamic-rails-error-pages. So, if the error page has errors, Rails recognises this and displays the plain text error seen here. Not as detailed as some of the below, but might be a quick steer for some people!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Rubytastic can  you please help me how can fix it?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The error you are experiencing is being thrown from

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb#L18-L22

This means the code your exceptions are getting rescued by are themselves throwing exceptions.
You can check your logs for text:

`Error during failsafe response:`

to identify what the exceptions really are originating from and thus solve your problem.

Comment: In other words, don't try to add a 1/0 in the application_controller.rb . It will raise an Exception on both the errors controller and your current controller, and of course you can't see your error page :).

Comment: @vladCovaliov May I ask what do you mean by *try to **add a 1/0** in*?

Comment: @iBug an intentional error or exception for the purposes of debugging, in this case a division by zero.

Answer (score 68):

Our [**`exception_handler`**](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler) gem can be used for Ruby on Rails custom error pages.

## How It Works

All Ruby on Rails exceptions are handled with [**`config.exceptions_app`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration). This is assigned in the `config/application.rb` or `config/environments/*.rb` files - it needs to be a callback:

> config.exceptions_app sets the exceptions application invoked by the ShowException middleware when an exception happens. Defaults to ActionDispatch::PublicExceptions.new(Rails.public_path).

Whenever Ruby on Rails hits an error, it invokes the [**`ShowExceptions`**](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb) middleware. This calls `exception_app` and sends the entire `request` (including `exception`) to the `exceptions_app`:

[image: Middleware-Powered Exceptions]

**`exceptions_app`** needs to [deliver a response](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb#L43). If not, the **`failsafe`** is loaded:

```
  # show_exceptions.rb#L38
  def render_exception(env, exception)
    wrapper = ExceptionWrapper.new(env, exception)
    status  = wrapper.status_code
    env["action_dispatch.exception"] = wrapper.exception
    env["PATH_INFO"] = "/#{status}"
    response = @exceptions_app.call(request.env) # => exceptions_app callback
    response[1]["X-Cascade"] == "pass" ? pass_response(status) : response
  rescue Exception => failsafe_error # => raised if exceptions_app false
    $stderr.puts "Error during failsafe response: #{failsafe_error}\n  #{failsafe_error.backtrace * "\n  "}"
    FAILSAFE_RESPONSE
  end
```

The **`failsafe`** is stored as [`FAILSAFE_RESPONSE`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb#L18-L22) at the top of `ShowExceptions`.

---

## Custom Error Pages

If you want to create custom error pages, you need to inject your own callback into `config.exceptions_app`. This can either be done in the application or with a gem:

[image: Code screenshot]

Notice how the *`call`* method is used - this is how a callback works. Ruby on Rails (`env`) is invoked when the request is received from the Internet; when an exception is raised, `env` is passed to `exceptions_app`.

The quality of your exception handling will be dependent on how you manage `env`. This is important; referencing `self.routes` does *not* carry the environment forward.

The best way is to handle exceptions with a separate controller. This allows you to handle the request as if it was just another view, granting access to the `layout` and other components (`model` / `email`).

---

There are *two* ways to handle exceptions:

1. **Overriding `404` / `500` routes**
2. **Invoking a controller**

Our gem was designed around our `controller` - invoked each time an `exception` is raised. This gives *full* control over the exception process, allowing for **100% branded layout**. It works 100% on Ruby on Rails 5.

---

## Managing Ruby on Rails' Exceptions

If you're not interested in the gem, let me explain the process:

All Ruby on Rails exceptions are handled with the [**`config.exceptions_app`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) callback. This is assigned in the `config/application.rb` or `config/environments/*.rb` files - it needs to be a callback:

> config.exceptions_app sets the exceptions application invoked by the ShowException middleware when an exception happens. Defaults to ActionDispatch::PublicExceptions.new(Rails.public_path).

Whenever an exception is raised by your app, the [`ShowExceptions`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb) middleware is invoked. This middleware builds the exception into the `request` and forwards it to the `config.exceptions_app` callback.

By default, `config.exceptions_app` points to the routes. This is why Rails comes with `404.html`, `500.html` and `422.html` in the `public` folder.

If you want to create *custom* exception pages, you need to override the `config.exceptions_app` callback - passing the erroneous request to an appropriate handler, be it a `controller` or `route`:

[ [middleware](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/richpeck/exception_handler/master/readme/middleware.jpg) ]

The two ways to manage this effectively are either to send the erroneous requests to the routes, or to invoke a controller.

The simplest - and most common - way is to forward the request to the routes; unfortunately, this ignores the request and prevents you from detailing the exceptions properly.

The best way is to invoke a separate controller. This will allow you to pass the entire request, allowing you to save it, email it or do a number of other things.

---

## 400 / 500 Errors

**Rails can *only* respond with HTTP-valid errors**.

Whilst the app's *exception* may be different, the returned status code *should* be either `40x` or `50x`. This is in line with the HTTP spec and outlined [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-status-option).

This means that no matter what exception handling solution you use/build, Ruby on Rails *needs* to return either `40x` or `50x` errors to the browser.

In other words, custom error pages have little to do with the *type* of exception - more how you're catching and serving the *browser response*.

By default, Ruby on Rails does this with `404.html`, `422.html` and `500.html` files in the `public` folder. If you want to handle the exception flow yourself, you need to remove these files and channel the erroneous requests to your own `exceptions_app` callback.

This can be done with the `routes` or with a `controller` (which I'll explain now):

---

### 1. Routes

The simplest way is to let the routes handle it.

This method is bloated and requires using multiple actions. It is also difficult to manage the responses.

This shows how to replace the `exceptions_app` with the routes directly:

```
# config/application.rb
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

Here is the code I have (Ruby 2.0.0 and Ruby on Rails 4.0):

**Application configuration**

```
#config/application.rb
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

**Routes**

```
#config/routes.rb
if Rails.env.production?
   get '404', to: 'application#page_not_found'
   get '422', to: 'application#server_error'
   get '500', to: 'application#server_error'
end
```

**Application Controller**

```
#controllers/application_controller.rb
def page_not_found
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/not_found_error', layout: 'layouts/application', status: 404 }
      format.all  { render nothing: true, status: 404 }
    end
  end

  def server_error
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/internal_server_error', layout: 'layouts/error', status: 500 }
      format.all  { render nothing: true, status: 500}
    end
  end
```

**Errors Layout** (totally static -- for server errors only)

```
#views/layouts/error.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= action_name.titleize %> :: <%= site_name %></title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <style>
    body {
        background: #fff;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .error_container {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
        width: 40%;
    }
    .error_container .error {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .error_container .error img {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto 25px auto;
    }
    .error_container .message strong {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #f00;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="error_container">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Error Views**

```
#views/errors/not_found_error.html.erb
<div class="error">
    <h2>Sorry, this page has moved, or doesn't exist!</h2>
</div>


#views/errors/internal_server_error.html.erb
<div class="error">
    <div class="message">
        <strong>Error!</strong>
        We're sorry, but our server is experiencing problems :(
    </div>
</div>
```

While many prefer the "routes" method for its simplicity, it is neither efficient nor modular. Indeed, if your application has any semblance of object orientation, you'll quickly dismiss it as a hack.

A *much* more resounding way is to use a custom controller to catch the pure exception. This way, you can construct the flow in accordance with your application's overall structure:

---

### 2. Controller

The other option is to route all the requests to a controller.

This is infinitely more powerful as it allows you to take the request (exception) and pass it through to the views, whilst managing it in the backend. This will allow for the likes of saving it to the database.

This [**gist**](https://gist.github.com/wojtha/8433843) shows how.

It means we can hook into the middleware and pass the entire *request* to a controller.

If this controller is backed by a model and views, we can extract it into a gem (which is what we did). If you wanted to do it manually, here's how:

---

**Configuration**

The beauty of this method is that it hooks directly into [`config.exceptions_app`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration). This means any exception can be handled natively, allowing for more efficiency. To make sure this works, you need to put the following code into `config/application.rb` (`exceptions_app` only works in `production` - `development` shows the errors):

```
#config/application.rb
config.exceptions_app = ->(env) { ExceptionController.action(:show).call(env) }
```

To test, you can set the "local" requests to false:

```
#config/environments/development.rb
config.consider_all_requests_local  = false # true
```

---

**Controller**

The next step is to add an `exception` controller. While this can be handled in `application_controller`, it is far better to extract into its own. Notice the call from the `application.rb` -- `ExceptionController.action(:show)`:

```
#app/controllers/exception_controller.rb
class ExceptionController < ApplicationController

  #Response
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  #Dependencies
  before_action :status

  #Layout
  layout :layout_status

  ####################
  #      Action      #
  ####################

  #Show
  def show
    respond_with status: @status
  end

  ####################
  #   Dependencies   #
  ####################

  protected

  #Info
  def status
    @exception  = env['action_dispatch.exception']
    @status     = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(env, @exception).status_code
    @response   = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.rescue_responses[@exception.class.name]
  end

  #Format
  def details
    @details ||= {}.tap do |h|
      I18n.with_options scope: [:exception, :show, @response], exception_name: @exception.class.name, exception_message: @exception.message do |i18n|
        h[:name]    = i18n.t "#{@exception.class.name.underscore}.title", default: i18n.t(:title, default: @exception.class.name)
        h[:message] = i18n.t "#{@exception.class.name.underscore}.description", default: i18n.t(:description, default: @exception.message)
      end
    end
  end
  helper_method :details

  ####################
  #      Layout      #
  ####################

  private

  #Layout
  def layout_status
    @status.to_s == "404" ? "application" : "error"
  end

end
```

---

**Views**

There are two views to add to get this working.

The first is the `exception/show` view, and second is the `layouts/error`. The first is to give the `exception_contoller#show` a view, and the second for `500` internal server errors.

```
#app/views/exception/show.html.erb
<h1><%= details[:name]    %></h1>
<p><%=  details[:message] %></p>


#app/views/layouts/error.html.erb (for 500 internal server errors)
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Error</title>
    <style>
      html {
        height: 100%;
        background: #fff;
      }
      body {
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      .error_container {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        margin: 10% auto 0 auto;
        width: 40%;
      }
      .error_container .error {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
      }
      .error_container .error img {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto 15px auto;
      }
      .error_container .message > * {
        display: block;
      }
      .error_container .message strong {
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #f00;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="error_container"><%= yield %></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

## Conclusion

The *exception* doesn't matter as much as the *error code*.

When Ruby on Rails raises an exception, it assigns one of the above HTTP response codes. These allow your browser to determine whether the request was successful.

When dealing with exceptions, you need to ensure you're able to handle `40*` errors (which will typically use the same layout as the rest of your application) and the `50*` errors (which will need their own layout).

In both cases, you'll be best using a separate `exception` controller, which will allow you to manage the `exception` as an object.

Comment: @RichardPeck great work, weird advertising thou. How do you go about having custom <title> message or at least Page Not Found? Thanks

Comment: Didn't intend to be advertising but thanks! What do you mean about the `<title>` message - where do you want to put it?

Comment: FYI you are being discussed on meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406788

Comment: "`exception_contoller`"?

Answer (score 20):

Error pages in the application should be as simple as it is possible. Same recommendation concerns their rendering. If your application returns a 500 HTTP response code it means that things got wrong already. And there is a chance you could not render an error page and display it to the user.

Ideally, error pages should be plain HTML pages served directly by your web server without hitting the the application server.

Speaking of Ruby on Rails implementation of this idea. It based on using asset pipeline for precompiling the HTML static pages.

Firstly add a new assets type (Ruby on Rails > 4.1):

```
# config/initializers/assets.rb

Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(404.html 500.html)
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app/assets/html')
Rails.application.config.assets.register_mime_type('text/html', '.html')
```

If a templating engine is used (e.g., Slim and [Haml](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haml)), register it via an initializer:

```
# For Slim
Rails.application.assets.register_engine('.slim', Slim::Template)
# For Haml
Rails.application.assets.register_engine('.haml', Tilt::HamlTemplate)
```

Now you ready to create pretty error pages in the app/assets/html directory using
your favorite template engine and Ruby on Rails' built-in view helpers.

### Tips for production

On production asset pipeline adds digest to compiled assets and stores files under default folder
(typically shared/public/assets on production server).
You can use capistrano to copy error pages to web server root:

```
# config/deploy.rb
# Capistrano 3 only

namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Copy compiled error pages to public'
  task :copy_error_pages do
    on roles(:all) do
      %w(404 500).each do |page|
        page_glob = "#{current_path}/public/#{fetch(:assets_prefix)}/#{page}*.html"
        # copy newest asset
        asset_file = capture :ruby, %Q{-e "print Dir.glob('#{page_glob}').max_by { |file| File.mtime(file) }"}
        if asset_file
          execute :cp, "#{asset_file} #{current_path}/public/#{page}.html"
        else
          error "Error #{page} asset does not exist"
        end
      end
    end
  end
  after :finishing, :copy_error_pages
end
```

And the last thing. Tell the web server to use these files for certain HTTP error codes (sample nginx configuration):

```
error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
error_page 404 /404.html;
```

### Sprocket 3 Update

For Sprocket 3 you need something like this (tested with Ruby on Rails 5):

```
# config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.configure do |env|
  env.register_transformer 'text/slim', 'text/html', Slim::Template
  env.register_mime_type 'text/slim', extensions: ['.html']
  env.register_engine '.slim', Slim::Template
end

# config/initializers/assets.rb
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(404.html 500.html)
Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app/assets/html')
```