# How redirect to 404 page in routes.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect

How can I redirect incorrect url to 404 page in routes.rb?
Now I use 2 examples code:

```
# example 1
match "/go/(*url)", to: redirect { |params, request| Addressable::URI.heuristic_parse(params[:url]).to_s }, as: :redirect, format: false

# example 2
match "/go/(*url)", to: redirect { |params, request| Addressable::URI.heuristic_parse(URI.encode(params[:url])).to_s }, as: :redirect, format: false
```

But when I try using russian words in 'url' parameter, in 1st example I get 500 page (bad URI), in 2nd - I get redirect to stage.example.xn--org-yedaaa1fbbb/

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some sample URLs that you're trying to use?

Comment: Some samples: stage.example.org/go/газета stage.example.org/go/газета.рф

Comment: if you want to redirect to 404 from within the controller you can also use `redirect_to("/404") && return`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want custom error pages, you'll be best looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103759/rails-4-custom-error-pages-for-404-500-and-where-is-the-default-500-error-mess) I wrote a few weeks ago

---

You need several important elements to create custom error routes:

-> **Add custom error handler in `application.rb`:**

```
# File: config/application.rb
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

-> **Create `/404` routes in your `routes.rb`:**

```
# File: config/routes.rb
if Rails.env.production?
   get '404', :to => 'application#page_not_found'
end
```

-> **Add `actions` to application controller to handle these routes**

```
# File: app/controllers/application_controller.rb
def page_not_found
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/not_found_error', layout: 'layouts/application', status: 404 }
      format.all  { render nothing: true, status: 404 }
    end
  end
```

This is obviously relatively basic, but hopefully it will give you some more ideas on what you can do

Answer (score 6):

The simplest thing to do is to make sure your routes do not match bad URLs.  By default Rails will return a 404 for routes that do not exist.

If you can't do this the default 404 page lives at `/404` so you can redirect to that location.  Something to keep in mind here, however, is that this type of redirect will perform a 301 Permanent Redirect instead of a 302.  This may not be the behavior that you want.  To do this you can do the following:

```
match "/go/(*url)", to: redirect('/404')
```

Instead, I'd recommend setting up a before filter in your action that instead raises a not found exception.  I'm not exactly sure if this exception is in the same place in Rails 4, but with Rails 3.2 I'm currently using:

```
raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
```

You can then do any processing and URL checking in the controller (if complicated checking of the URL format is required).