# How to handle "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request" in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, routes, bad-request

I am facing an error when a user enters search string as '%' in url itself.  After entering my url looks as

```
 http://localhost:3000/search/%
```

Now its showing "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - http://localhost:3000/search/%". I want to redirect to some other page and show, a bad request image when the error occurs. Please suggest me some ideas to do this.

I have attached the error image. [image]

**UPDATE**

I have tried the below.

config/application.rb:

```
 config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

config/routes.rb:

```
match "/400", :to => "errors#bad_request"
```

It's not coming inside the bad_request method.

In Log i am getting error as

```
 Invalid request: Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checkout this [**gem 'utf8-cleaner'**](https://github.com/singlebrook/utf8-cleaner) which removes invalid `UTF-8` characters from the environment so that your app doesn't choke on them.

If you want custom error pages: then look at **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653761/how-redirect-to-404-page-in-routes-rb#answer-19654378)**

Comment: Both are not working. First of all the control is not coming to the routes itself. I guess the problem is with thin