# raising exception in before_action short-circuits custom 404 page handler

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm successfully using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4983354/93995) to programmatically send users to a custom 404 page by raising a `RoutingError` in a before_action in my controller if there is a problem (e.g. bad params):

```
before_action :check_invalid_params

def check_invalid_params
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found') if params[:foo].present?
end
```

This has worked great in my controllers, but I recently tried to DRY up some common error checking into the ApplicationController superclass so that the before_action would be applied to *all* my controllers.

Unfortunately it seems that if you throw an exception from a before_action callback in ApplicationController, custom error page handling gets short-circuited, and you wind up with a generic 500 error that the middleware generates (like like on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103759/rails-4-custom-error-pages-for-404-500-and-where-is-the-default-500-error-mess)):

```
500 Internal Server Error
If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's     
log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong.
```

Is there a way to raise an exception from a before_action in ApplicationController and still have custom error page handling? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to avoid raise an error if you are able to handle it by checking the params. So for your case I will do this:

```
def check_invalid_params
  render json:{error: 'foo not found'}, :status => 422 if params[:foo].present?
end
```

if you call a method that could fail

```
def some_before_action
  call_external_service
rescue
  render json:{error: 'Internal Server Error'}, :status => 500
end
```

you can render whatever you want at that point(json is an easy example)