# Create custom Rails error Partial on Homepage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, error-handling

In many cases people want to have separate error pages but in my case I want an custom error page on my homepage.

I found the link http://makandracards.com/makandra/12807-custom-error-pages-in-rails-3-2 this helps to make separate error pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've made the following to help this:

**Routes.rb:**

```
  match '/404', :to => 'home#not_found'
  match '/422', :to => 'home#rejected'
  match '/500', :to => 'home#server_error'
```

**Application.rb**

```
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

**Home_controller.rb**

```
  def not_found
    @errors = I18n.t("home.errors.error_404")
    render 'index'
  end

  def rejected
    @errors = I18n.t("home.errors.error_422")
    render 'index'
  end

  def server_error
    @errors = I18n.t("home.errors.error_500")
    render 'index'
  end
```

**On my home/index page:**

```
<%= render :partial => 'errors', :errors => @errors %>
```

**And a simple partial _errors:**

```
<div class="row">
  <% if @errors %>
  <div class="alert alert-wide alert-info">
    <p style="display:inline"><%= @errors %></p>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've worked extensively on this, and have created a [gem called `exceptions_handler`](https://rubygems.org/gems/exception_handler) to make it easier for people to use

You can see a good tutorial [here](https://gist.github.com/wojtha/8433843):

I've also written an exhaustive answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103759/rails-4-custom-error-pages-for-404-500-and-where-is-the-default-500-error-mess/19279062#19279062)

--

**`exceptions_app`**

The bottom line with your own error pages is to capture the error using the [`exceptions_app`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) middleware hook in Rails:

> `config.exceptions_app` sets the exceptions application invoked by the `ShowExceptionmiddleware` when an exception happens. Defaults to `ActionDispatch::PublicExceptions.new(Rails.public_path)`.

As the first answer has posted, you should apply this to your `config/application.rb`, but I would disagree with sending the request to the routes file directly

--

**Controller**

A better  way is to send the request to a controller action (we use `exceptions#show`):

```
#config/application.rb
config.exceptions_app = ->(env) { ExceptionController.action(:show).call(env) }

#app/controllers/exception_controller.rb
class ExceptionController < ActionController::Base

    #Response
    respond_to :html, :xml, :json

#Dependencies
before_action :status

    def show
       render "index"
    end

    private

    def status
      @exception  = env['action_dispatch.exception']
      @status     = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(env, @exception).status_code
      @response   = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.rescue_responses[@exception.class.name]
    end

end
```

--

**Views**

This will allow you to create the following views:

```
#app/views/application/index.html.erb
<% render partial: "errors" if @status.present? %>
```