# Couldn't find MyController with id=213123123

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

`http://myside.com/MyControllers/213123123` gives me `Couldn't find MyController with id=213123123`

```
def show
  render :text=>'testing ....'  
  begin
    @ingredient = MyController.find(params[:id])
  rescue RecordNotFound => e
    puts "Test........"
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @ingredient }
  end
end
```

**render :text=>'testing ....' is not rendring if invalid id given**
Couldn't find MyController with id=213123123

Any one guide me what will be the right syntax

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am try to handle exception not throw and if wrong id ifs passed then 404 page will be show

Comment: Try generalizing the rescue at first, by removing the case (RecordNotFound => e) and see if it works. If it does, then check how you should syntactically put it.

Comment: You cannot call render and then respond_to. You will get something like double rendering error.

Answer (score 0):

You've got several important syntax issues:

> 1. Your routes seem malformed ([you need to use `snake_case` rather than `CamelCase`](http://blog.lmorchard.com/2013/01/23/naming-conventions))
> 2. You'll be better using the [`exception_app`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) middleware hook to capture the exception

I would fix these as follows:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :my_controllers #-> domain.com/my_controllers/:id

#app/controllers/my_controllers_controller.rb
Class MyController < ApplicationController
   def show
       @ingredient = MyController.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

---

[**exceptions_app**](https://gist.github.com/wojtha/8433843)

I've actually written extensively about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103759/rails-4-custom-error-pages-for-404-500-and-where-is-the-default-500-error-mess/19279062#19279062) & [written a gem here](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler) & there is a great [github gist here](https://gist.github.com/wojtha/8433843)

This will then give you the ability to capture any exceptions using the `exceptions_app` middleware hook:

```
#config/application.rb
config.exceptions_app = ->(env) { ExceptionController.action(:show).call(env) }
```

This will allow you to route any exceptions through a separate controller called `ExceptionController`:

```
#app/controllers/exception_controller.rb
Class ExceptionController < ApplicationController
   layout 'application'

   def show
     @exception       = env['action_dispatch.exception']
     @status_code     = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(env, @exception).status_code
     @rescue_response = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.rescue_responses[@exception.class.name]

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { render :show, status: @status_code, layout: !request.xhr? }
       format.xml  { render xml: details, root: "error", status: @status_code }
       format.json { render json: {error: details}, status: @status_code }
     end
  end
end

#app/views/exception/show.html.erb
Put what you want here
```

This will help you capture the exceptions - if you'd like to test in development, you should do this:

```
#config/environments/development.rb
config.consider_all_requests_local = false
```