# Rails 4 Custom Error Handling for Specific ContentTypes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing an API-only application using Rails 4.

The ActionControllers render templates specific to certain content types (like .html and .json)

So my question is, can I return custom errors (404, 500 etc.) specific to certain content-types sent in the request (e.g. Content-Type : application/json)?

Rails otherwise sends default 404.html, which doesn't work well with clients expecting a JSON-encoded result.

Comment: This seems closely related to what you are trying to do, you will need to adapt this for 500's of course: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385799/how-to-redirect-to-a-404-in-rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your question is not directly clear, here's what I'd be looking at...

--

**Error Handling**

We handle custom error pages using the [`config.exceptions_app`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration) middleware hook

We've written a gem for it called [`exception_handler`](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler) & have a popular answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103759/rails-4-custom-error-pages-for-404-500-and-where-is-the-default-500-error-mess/19279062#19279062). There's also a [great github gist here](https://gist.github.com/wojtha/8433843)

I would recommend using the `exceptions_app` middleware hook, with an accompanying controller to capture & respond to the errors:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
config.consider_all_requests_local = false # true -> for testing

#config/application.rb
config.exceptions_app = ->(env) { ExceptionController.action(:show).call(env) }

#app/controllers/exception_controller.rb
Class ExceptionController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :json, :html

   def show
        @exception       = env['action_dispatch.exception']
        @status_code     = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(env, @exception).status_code
        @rescue_response = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.rescue_responses[@exception.class.name]
        respond_with @rescue_response
   end

end
```

This will allow you to create the custom pages you need, as well as being able to return the required `mime` types

--

**`respond_to`**

As a general rule, Rails allows you to use the [`respond_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html#method-i-respond_to) code block to deliver different responses to different [`mime` types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)

You can use the block in two ways:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   def your_action
      respond_to do |format|
         format.json
         format.html
      end
   end
end
```

Alternatively, you can use the `respond_to` & `respond_with` methods in tandem:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
Class YourController < ApplicationController
   respond_to :js, :json, :html

   def your_action
      @your_variable = "test"
      respond_with @your_variable #-> responds with appropriate mime-type
   end

end
```

--

**Responses**

If you want to issue a [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)-only response, you need to use all of the above code to create a controller which allows you to pass the JSON response.

You must remember that JSON responses are just a *type* of data response -- specifically, just providing a nested hash of all the data you respond with.

If you want to receive a JSON response to your errors, you basically need to be able to create a controller to handle the correct mime-type. What I've recommended above will do that for you