# How to check if variable has error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to check if the variable has error in my controller before going to view.

in my controller:

```
def index
    @sample_model = Model.all
    rescue => e
    flash.now[:alert] = e.message
end
```

for example I have error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Table 'models' doesn't exist: ...`

I want to check if first before going to view so I can show it my flash.

Comment: Do you have a problem with the standard way rails will display the error? That is, the error as it appears if you remove your `rescue` clause? If so, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am looking forward to seeing a solution (this is not an answer in itself); I wanted to highlight several points:

---

> I want to check if first before going to view **so I can show it my
>   flash.**

How do you expect to show an error in your flash?

Much of the time, errors of this nature cause the equivalent of a [`fatal exception`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatal_exception_error), preventing the application from making any progress.

When this type of thing happens, Rails has some middleware which catches the exception, passing it to the error handling pages. I'll explain this in a minute.

The fact remains, though, that if you're going to receive an error - how do you expect the rest of your stack to work? **Maybe the MYSQL table doesn't exist** -- what if you're calling the same data in the layout or something?

---

What you're looking for is one of two things:

> 1. A way to handle *specific* errors (IE no data)
> 2. A way to rescue exceptions in a *controlled* manner (IE without having the default "exception" page from Rails.

---

[**config.exceptions_app**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration)

This is not the answer, but it will help...

All Rails exceptions are handled by a middleware hook called `config.exceptions_app`:

[image]

The *actual* middleware is `ActionDispatch::ShowException`, which can be seen [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f49d20ef36c2d339e7a988fdc52981cdb95af22f/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb#L24).

Any of the "custom exception page" tutorials you get will essentially hook into the `config.exceptions_app` middleware, either with `self.routes` or a controller call.

I've been involved with [custom error pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103759/rails-4-custom-error-pages-for-404-500-and-where-is-the-default-500-error-mess) for some time; [I wrote a gem](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler) for it. There are several important points to understand with it.

Rails invokes 2 sets of errors - `40x` & `50x`:

- `40x` (like `404`) are for *missing resources*
- `50x` (like `500`) are for *server faults*.

The difference between the two is that 404 errors (either no routes, or no data), are not fatal. 500 errors *are* fatal (as they prevent your app from functioning).

500 errors cannot be rescued with the rest of your app's infrastructure; they could be anything from your database having no connection to the variable not having any values.

---

**What type of errors are you expecting to rescue?**

As such, if it's a "no data" error, you'll be able to handle that with `@variable.nil?` conditions.

If it's something more serious (a problem further up the stack), what do you expect to happen? That your view & layout will load with no data? What if your DB connectivity is broken?

--

The best recommendation I can give is to handle any app-level exceptions within your controller & view, EG:

```
#app/views/data/object.html.erb
<% if @variable.any? %>
```

If you want to "prettify" your error pages, you'll be best using one of the recommendations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103759/rails-4-custom-error-pages-for-404-500-and-where-is-the-default-500-error-mess), or simply using the [`exception_handler`](https://github.com/richpeck/exception_handler) gem I helped write.

Comment: I think this is a far better answer to the one I entered.

Comment: Thanks buddy, that means a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
@sample_models.select{|sm| sm.errors.present?}.collect(&:errors)
```

Comment: I tried something like that but no luck. I got this instead `<NoMethodError: undefined method 'errors' for #<#<Class:0x007f9489d7ccb8>:0x007f9489dd3608>>`

Comment: Note that @sample_model is a collection of model objects - not one.The collection doesn't have an errors method.