# Custom error page 404/500 but getting a 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-error-pages, custom-error-handling

I am trying to customize my 404/422/500 error pages and for some reason I get a blank page with a "500 Internal Server Error". However, in another project the code below works perfectly fine. I hope someone can help me out.

Here are my codes :

Application.rb

```
module Realbeez
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.generators do |generate|
      generate.assets false
      generate.helper false
      generate.test_framework  :test_unit, fixture: false
      # For error message customizing
      config.exceptions_app = self.routes
    end
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2
  end
end
```

My routes:

```
 get '/404', to: "errors#not_found"
 get '/422', to: "errors#unacceptable"
 get '/500', to: "errors#internal_error"
```

My controller ErrorsController:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController

  def not_found
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render status: 404 }
    end
  end

  def unacceptable
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render status: 422 }
    end
  end

  def internal_error
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render status: 500 }
    end
  end

end
```

I get the following message in the rails server maybe it can help :

```
Error during failsafe response: ErrorsController
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/pundit-2.1.0/lib/pundit.rb:192:in `verify_authorized'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:426:in `block in make_lambda'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:236:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:517:in `block in invoke_after'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:517:in `each'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:517:in `invoke_after'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:133:in `run_callbacks'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionview-5.2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:51:in `render_exception'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:36:in `rescue in call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:29:in `perform_request'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.1.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.1.0/lib/puma/server.rb:664:in `handle_request'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.1.0/lib/puma/server.rb:467:in `process_client'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.1.0/lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
  /Users/steven/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.1.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Thanks

Comment: related topic, but i did not find the solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103759/rails-4-custom-error-pages-for-404-500-and-where-is-the-default-500-error-mess

Answer (score 0):

You can just customize the html error pages in the "public" folder. Did you try it ?

Comment: Hi Luksmo, thanks for your reply. I would rather use an errors controller and be able to use html.erb file in the views.